# auto increment option error in sqlite3

Tags: sql

```
create table filemanager(oid AUTO_INCREMENT INT PRIMARY KEY,filepath Text unique);
insert into filemanager(filepath)values("c:\a.txt")
select *from filemanager
```

Output: `|c:\a.txt`

Kindly let me know what  I am missing here.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Correct create command is:

```
create table filemanager (
  oid integer primary key autoincrement,
  filepath text unique);
```

Comment: Thanks keltar.It's working.But can I use BIG INT instead of integer?This is because the range of integer is less than BIG INT.

Comment: sqlite defines autoincrement only for integer. However, i doubt it follows types you specified because they use dynamic typing (e.g. you can set text data into int column - SQL standard forbids that, but not sqlite).

Answer (score 1):

Check this <kbd>[**demo SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d3293/1/0)</kbd>

`AUTOINCREMENT` write always last,

#### Create Table,

```
create table filemanager(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    filepath Text unique
);
insert into filemanager(filepath)values("c:\a.txt");
```

#### Select Query

```
select * from filemanager;
```